# how do we highlight a row in the gridview on selection of a dropdown in the same? using javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

On row data bound, the gridview is being populated, and how do we higlight one particular row after a dropdown is selected in that same row. [C# .net]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the dropdown ID and add class. Finding ID in server control may be vary in different case.

```
 $("[id*=GridViewID] td select").change(function () {
            $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).addClass("HighLightRow");
});
```

CSS:

```
.HighLightRow
 {
     background-color: #A1DCF2;
 }
```

Note : Don't forget to include JQuery Library.